# Rearrange an expression according to known items

Tags: algebraic-manipulation

I have this expresion:

$\qquad q_{aft}=-i\,f \left(a_2\right){}^{\dagger }+i\,f \left(a_2\right){}^{\dagger }-\left(a_1\right){}^{\dagger }-a_1$

Defining

$\qquad q_{0_1}=a_1+(a_1)^\dagger$

and

$\qquad p_{0_2}=-i\,(a_2-(a_2)^\dagger)$

straightforwardly you can see that

$\qquad q_{aft}=-(q_{0_1}+fp_{0_2})$

Is there any way to make this identification and manipulation with *Mathematica*? Or more generaly, is there some kind of `Collect` function that allow to rearrange an expresion with items previously defined like $p_{0_2}$ and $q_{0_1}$?

Comment: Are you working with traditional form expressions in your _Mathematica_ notebook?

Comment: Yes, but i'm working with this package: http://homepage.cem.itesm.mx/lgomez/quantum/ @m_goldberg

Answer (score 1):

I think i've found one solution to my trouble: [`PolynomialReduce`] do exactly what i wanted. Given this relations,

```
b1= -a1 - I f SuperDagger[a2]
b2=-a2 - I SuperStar[f] SuperDagger[a1]
q1b = Refine[1/Sqrt[2] (b1 + SuperDagger[b1]), f \[Element] Reals]
```

Using [`PolynomialReduce`] we get

```
   PolynomialReduce[q1b, {q1a, p2a, p1a, q2a}, {a1, SuperDagger[a1], a2,SuperDagger[a2]}]
   ={{-1, -f, 0, 0}, 0}
```

As i expected... But new problems arise! If i write

```
    PolynomialReduce[q2b, {q1a, p2a, p1a, q2a}, {a1, SuperDagger[a1], a2,SuperDagger[a2]}]={{I f, -I, 0, 0}, -I Sqrt[2] f SuperDagger[a1] - 
    Sqrt[2] SuperDagger[a2]}
```

Unfortunately, Mathemathica represents the reduction in terms of the first terms (`q1a`and `p2a`in this case) giving a non-null remainder. However if i write this

```
   PolynomialReduce[q2b, {q2a, p1a, p2a, q2a}, {a1, SuperDagger[a1], a2, 
   SuperDagger[a2]}]={{-1, -f, 0, 0}, 0}
```

So i have a new question: Is there any way to demand a null-remainder(if it exists) providing to Mathemathica a group of polynomials to work with?